# Using params in view in kemal

Tags: parameters, sinatra, kemal

I have a simple ruby/sinatra app I am attempting to migrate to crystal/kemal.  When user submits form choice, the sinatra version POSTs the params as a hash

```
{"category"=>["selection1", "selection2",..]}
```

I then pass the selections to the view by `render index.erb` in the `post` route.  However in kemal I can collect the params but cannot figure out how to access them in the view.  I keep getting the error `undefined local variable or method`.

How do I make the view access the submitted params?

Here is the sinatra code for the `post` route:

```
post '/' do
  if params.values.flatten.length < 1
    flash[:warning] = "Please choose at least one AED"
    redirect '/'
  else
    params
    erb :index
  end
end
```

and the corresponding kemal code:

```
post "/" do |env|
  selected_drugs = env.params.body.fetch_all("drugs")
  if selected_drugs.size < 1
    env.flash["warning"] = "Please choose at least one AED"
    render "src/views/index.ecr"
  else
    selected_drugs
    render "src/views/index.ecr"
  end
end
Kemal.run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not define the variable holding params in all routes that used `index.ecr`.  Once that was done it worked.  Interesting that I didn't have to define it in some routes for sinatra, though.